# can't install cocoapods-keys in my M1 macbook

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

I tried to run pod install, it gives me the following error

```
[!] Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-keys` be installed. Please install it and try installation again.
```

When I try to install cocoapods-keys, with this command gem install cocoapods-keys --user-install

it tells me the it's successfully installed

```
Successfully installed cocoapods-keys-2.2.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-keys-2.2.1
Done installing documentation for cocoapods-keys after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But when I try to run pod install again it still tells me it's not installed
What's wrong?
Thank you in advance

Comment: https://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/#i-installed-gems-with---user-install-and-their-commands-are-not-available

Comment: You can try `arch -x86_64 pod install` for M1 Chip MacBook

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following suggestion and it worked for me.

- [Solution](https://github.com/orta/cocoapods-keys/issues/217#issuecomment-1005712448)